# Can I deploy a file on change inside PhpStorm?

Tags: npm, sass, ide, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm as my IDE and configured Sass to compile into my css file for my WordPress site. I have set up auto upload, which works on the file I am working on but not my `style.css` as my node watcher is updating it, not me.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Use **File Watcher** functionality in PhpStorm to initiate compilation of your Sass from inside the IDE (basically, IDE will run compilation command when file gets modified). Once compilation is done and if you have correctly configured "Output paths to refresh" field there .. IDE will check those files for any changes, if it will see the change in timestamp (file is modified) it will also include it in the auto deployment. For that you may need to have "Skip external changes" option disabled (from Deployment settings). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-watchers.html

Comment: But if you want to keep compiling it outside ... then after compilation is done just manually hit "File | Reload All from Disk" -- IDE will see scan all project files for external modifications, will see the changes and will trigger the auto upload. Obviously, this is less convenient as you need to manually hit that action (after the compilation is done ... which can take some time .. and not always the same amount of time).

Comment: NOTE: make sure to use right parameters for your Sass compiler .. as there are a few of them: old/deprecated Ruby based one, new (JS-based?) one, then node-sass as well. They all have different command line parameters.